# How to Avoid ConcurrentModificationException in that case?

Tags: java, list, for-loop, concurrentmodification

I understand that when I try to modify (add in that case) the list I got ConcurrentModificationException, but what is the best solution to fix that?

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Child> entry : children.entrySet() {
     childEvent.child = entry.getValue();
     if (childEvent.getDate() != null && childEvent.getDate().equals(selectedDate)) {
         if(this.selectedDayevents.isEmpty()) {
             // List                                
             this.selectedDayevents.add(childEvent);
          }
         for (CareDay selectedCareDay : this.selectedDayevents) {
             // Here I have to combine data in some cases...
         }
     }  
}
```

Comment: Collect the changes in an other `Map`, then use `Map.addAll` after you did loop over the entries.

Comment: But I need to add data inside the second for-loop to CareDay-objects so I think that it is not the solution to collect every changed object to third List,Map etc and then I have to loop those again (I think)

Comment: If you need to modify list during iterating - use this list `Iterator` to `add` and `remove` elements or create new list and add/remove to/from it.

Comment: Please show the failing code in your [mcve]. Apparently the `add` statement you're showing is not the one that is failing? In that case you should remove it to make the example *minimal* , and please add the statement this *is* failing. Also please indent the code correctly - it's hardly possible to read it now.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way around this problem is to iterate over a *copy* of the entry set:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Child> entry : new HashSet<>(children.entrySet())) {
    // same code
}
```

If your map is not too big and you’re not doing it very often, you won’t notice a difference in performance.

Answer (score -1):

If your requirement is to enable concurrent access to the collection, then you should explore java concurrency APIs and especially [ConcurrentHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) or [ConcurrentSkipListMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html) for your case.

Comment: The OP didn't mention anything related to concurrent access. If you want to ask the OP a question, please use comments when you have enough reputation to do so.

Comment: Erwin, my answer clearly starts with "If your requirement is...", hence the necessary conditional nature of the answer is explicitly mentioned.